# ms chart how do i compare datapoint yvalue

Tags: c#, mschart

i am doing this:

```
        foreach (DataPoint point in chart1.Series[0].Points)
        {
            if (point.yvalue > mean*1.3) ... 

            ....
        }
```

i need to be able to compare every yvalue of every point to a double. how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends if you have multiple Y Values per Point or not (depending on the chartArea type)

First Case : X/Y Values are bijective (1X Val <-> 1Y Val) (most frequent case):

```
    foreach (DataPoint point in chart.Series[0].Points)
            {
                if (point.YValues[0] > myValueToCompareTo)
                     //Do My Stuff;

            }
```

Second case : (1X Val -> NY Val) iterate over each Y Value for each point

```
    foreach (DataPoint point in chart.Series[0].Points)
            {                    
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j <point.YValues.Length; j++)
                    if (point.YValues[j] > myValueToCompareTo) 
                         //Do My Stuff;
            }
```